# Mechanism of Views

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, db2, view

I know that View is nothing but the stored select query of a table. When ever we call the view, that select query will trigger in the back-end to display as the result of the view.

"I also know that we can update/insert/delete the data from the VIEW and all the modifications we did for view will be reflected in the underlying table"

But this is what confusing me.

Q1: If the view is a simple select query and when ever it called, it will execute the select query form back-end, How does the update/insert will work on the view. I don't understand how the update/insert will work on "Select query" alias VIEW?

Q2: I know that a views can be refreshed by executing the select on underlying table. But how the changes made to view will effect the underlying table's Data?

When we did the update/delete/insert what mechanism is going on in the back end to update the view as well as underlying table?

[image: table_name: cyberarc, View_name: v_cyberarc]

Answer (score 1):

First of all understand view never refreshed (except Materialized view in Oracle). 
Assume you have created view like below
create view myview as select * from t;

That view query will be stored in database. Whenever you call that view then database will load that stored query and execute eg
select * from myview

in the above case database will change the query to like below and execute
select * from (select * from t);

So database always fetch data from the base table not from view (or refresh view).

For your first question, see the below eg
update myview set c1 = 123;
In this case db will change this update to like below
update (select * from t) set c1 = 123;
This is feasible in any rdbms.

For your second question, whatever data change using view will affect the base table data only not change/update the view.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Q1. I tried to run your update statement in sql server. It is giving syntax error. screen shot attached for reference.

Q2. You said materialized views in oracle are the only one which can be refreshed. How does the materializes views in MS SQL / Postgres works?

Comment: Q1. need to check that. Q2 MS SQL have indexed view and postgres have MATERIALIZED VIEW (I am not sure it will support all the features which support in Oracle)